# Use fields specifier for maps.googleapis?

Tags: json, google-maps, get, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to get a subset of the json return from a maps.googleapis call. Specifically the location which is in the body of the current return below:

```
"location" : {
    "lat" : 44.0581728,
    "lng" : -121.3153096
}
```

If I make a get request to: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=bend&sensor=false
This is the result:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Bend",
               "short_name" : "Bend",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Deschutes County",
               "short_name" : "Deschutes County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Oregon",
               "short_name" : "OR",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Bend, OR, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 44.1231839,
                  "lng" : -121.248579
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 43.999089,
                  "lng" : -121.3807099
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 44.0581728,
               "lng" : -121.3153096
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 44.1231839,
                  "lng" : -121.248579
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 43.999089,
                  "lng" : -121.3807099
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJUdLTpf_AuFQRtNEgx6zniBA",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I tried adding &fields=location to the get request but it returns the same info. I don't see a clear method of doing this on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingRequests

Any help appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The location you need is present in the geometry. The JSON object has location property under geometry field.

Comment: Thank you. I just want the get request to return location so I don't have parse it. I'm not sure how to specify that in the get request though..